# Como obter um número aleatório que não esteja em uma array em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho uma array de números e gostaria de gerar um número aleatório que não esteja nessa lista.

```
const idList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

do {
  const id = Math.floor(Math.random() * idLists.length + 1);
} while (!idLists.includes(id));
```

Pensei em algo assim, mas não funcionou :/

Comment: O certo seria repetir enquanto o id gerado esteja na lista (ou seja, sem o `!` na condição do while. Mas cai dar erro porque a variável se chama `idList`, mas no loop vc usa `idLists`. E a forma como vc fez o cálculo sempre vai gerar um número entre 1 e 5, então é um loop infinito... Em vez de usar `length`, use um número maior que não esteja no array...

Answer (score 0):

Cara, acho que a escalabilidade dessa solução é bem restrita dado o limite que tu tem que especificar pra gerar o número randômico, mas algo assim vai te ajudar:

```
const idList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function geraNumeroAleatorio(){
    let min = 0, 
        max = 9,
        numeroAleatorio;

    do{
        numeroAleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    } while(idList.includes(numeroAleatorio))
    
    return numeroAleatorio;
}
```

Apenas altera o valor de `max` pra algo mais apropriado pra ti (801281927162816829617 por ex, pois quanto maior esse número maior a possibilidade de valores que a função pode gerar).

Answer (score -1):

Tenta fazer algo assim:

```
const numeroMaximo = 100;
const numeroMinimo = idList.length
console.log(Math.ceil(Math.random() * (numeroMaximo - numeroMinimo  + 1 ) + numeroMinimo));
```

Assim o numero gerado estará entre `numeroMinimo` e `numeroMaximo`